# Python: If condition appears to be met but isn't triggering

Tags: python, if-statement, infinite-loop

I know this seems like it should be very simple, but at this point I'm at my wit's end trying to figure this out. I've coded up a calculator in python, but for some reason the ending if-else statement is only firing the else segment.

```
import sys
import re

#setting values
x = 0
n = '+'
y = 0
#valid input flag
valid = True
#continue operations flag
run = True
again = "k"

#addition function
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

#subtraction function
def subtract(x, y):
    return x - y

#multiplication function
def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y

#division function
def divide(x, y):
    return x / y

#continuation loop
while run == True:
    #Prompt for and accept input
    equation = raw_input("Please insert a function in the form of 'operand' 'operator' 'operand' (x + y): ")
    equation.strip()
    #Divide input into 3 parts by spaces
    pieces = re.split('\s+', equation)

    #set part 1 = x as float
    x = pieces[0]
    try:
        x = float(x)
    except:
        print "x must be a number"
        valid = False

    #set part 2 = operator
    if valid == True:
        try:
            n = pieces[1]
        except:
            print "Please use valid formating (x [] y)."
            valid = False

    #set part 3 = y as float
    if valid == True:
        y = pieces[2]
        try:
            y = float(y)
        except:
            print "y must be a number"
            valid = False

    #If input is valid, do requested calculations
    while valid == True:
        if n == '+' :
            print equation + " =", add(x,y)

        elif n == '-' :
            print equation, " =", subtract(x,y)

        elif n == '*' :
            print equation, "*", y, " =", multiply(x,y)

        elif n == '/' :
            if y == 0:
                print "You cannot divide by zero."

            else:
                print equation, " =", divide(x,y)

        else:
            print "Please use an appropriate operator ( + - * / )."

#play again
    again = raw_input("Play again? ")
    print again

    if again == ("yes", "y", "YES", "Yes","yes"):
        run = True
        print "yes'd"

    else:
        print "no'd"
        run = False
```

When I run this code, I get two different problems:
If I enter a valid input (ie: 2 + 2), then my output is

"2 + 2 = 4.0"

"2 + 2 = 4.0"

"2 + 2 = 4.0"

repeating forever.

If I enter an invalid input, I get the "Play again? " Prompt, but 
no matter what I enter, the else statement fires. 
(for instance, in the case that I enter "yes" into "Play again? ", it will print:
"yes"  (<-- this is from "print again" line )
"no'd" (<-- this is from "else: print "no'd" )

I dont know how to solve either of these problems at this point, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Thank you everyone, I wish I could check mark all of you for helping me understand different things about what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `while valid == True:`, you never change the value of `valid`, so it's always `True` and the loop is infinite. I don't see why it's even a loop - change it to `if` like the blocks above it and it will behave as expected.

Also, in `if again == ("yes", "y", "YES", "Yes","yes"):`, change `==` to `in` and it will behave as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should replace this code:

```
while valid == True:
    if n == '+' :
        print equation + " =", add(x,y)

    elif n == '-' :
        print equation, " =", subtract(x,y)

    elif n == '*' :
        print equation, "*", y, " =", multiply(x,y)

    elif n == '/' :
        if y == 0:
            print "You cannot divide by zero."

        else:
            print equation, " =", divide(x,y)

    else:
        print "Please use an appropriate operator ( + - * / )."
```

With this...

```
if valid:
```

Or...

```
while valid == True:
    # Insert your previous code here.
    break
```

*You could also just simply set valid to false at the bottom of your loop too. That would work.*

I think valid is constantly true in this case. You have also written while valid is true, which means it will keep iterating over the loop until valid is equalled to false. It appears that within this block of code in the while loop, valid isn't switched to false.

Answer (score 1):

`while valid == True:` should probably be `if valid == True`

and for your second problem:

`if again == ("yes", "y", "YES", "Yes","yes"):`  should probably be:

```
again = again.lower();
if again == "yes" or again == "y":
```

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is looping because of

```
while valid == True:
```

Replace the loop with the if statement

---

You get "no'd" because of

```
if again == ("yes", "y", "YES", "Yes", "yes"):
```

Here you are equating string with a tuple, instead of checking whether the string is contained within a tuple. Try this instead:

```
if again in ("yes", "y", "YES", "Yes""):
```